# Not able to start a party in roblox game

Tags: roblox

I was playing *Work at a Pizza Place* in Roblox and I was wondering how to start a party. Around 6 months ago, I could start a party in *Work at a Pizza Place*, but now I can't. Why is this so?

Comment: Like a party in work at a pizza place or a roblox party?

Answer (score -5):

I believe that the owner updated Work at a Pizza Place so that now you can't start a party while in it. Hope this was helpful.